# ref no longer reactive within a reactive array object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n, vue-composition-api

The following code works fine. When we change the language the text gets updated correctly thanks to the `ref`:

```js
const mainNavigationLinks = computed(() => [
  { label: context.root.$t('navigationMenu.home') },
  { label: context.root.$t('navigationMenu.tickets') },
])

return {
  mainNavigationLinks,
}
```

But what we would really like is to have the `mainNavigationLinks` as a `reactive` object, so we can add and remove items from the array and have Vue update the components accordingly with the correct translations by using the `ref` within the `array`. According to the [Vue docs](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#ref) this should be possible

However, when we try the code below we see that the label is no longer reactive:

```js
const mainNavigation = reactive([
  { label: context.root.$t('navigationMenu.home') },
  { label: context.root.$t('navigationMenu.tickets') },
])

const mainNavigationLinks = computed(() => mainNavigation)
```

What are we missing here to be able to add items to the array and still have it reactive? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you want is to have the array be reactive, but the items within the array be computed properties.

```
const mainNavigation = reactive([
  { label: computed(() => context.root.$t('navigationMenu.home')) },
  { label: computed(() => context.root.$t('navigationMenu.tickets')) },
])
```

Alternatively, you might be able to get away with not using `computed` at all here, as long as each `label` property refers to a function that you have to call:

```
const mainNavigation = reactive([
  { label: () => context.root.$t('navigationMenu.home') },
  { label: () => context.root.$t('navigationMenu.tickets') },
])
```

That's the main idea: each `label` needs to be evaluated at the time it is used, which is why it must be either a `computed` property (you benefit from caching) or a function. Your code doesn't work because you are getting the label translations immediately when you constructed the array.

Comment: Thank you for the help. What you say seems logical but when I try  the `computed` version it complains with `type check failed for prop "label". Expected Number, String, got Object `. With the anonymous functions used as an IIFE it displays the text but it loses reactivity again.

Comment: For point #1 you might need to manually unwrap it `:label="mainNavigation[0].label.value"`; for #2 it shouldn't be invoked immediately in the array, it has to be kept in the array as a function that you call like `:label="mainNavigation[0].label()"`, if that is what you did but it still doesn't work then that's odd and I have no explanation.

Comment: Weird that we need to manually unwrap it. Made an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues/342) for this.